# How a unique MAC address is maintained by the manufactures?

Tags: networking, tcp

I understand that the MAC address is flashed on the NIC. It is supposed to be unique as is is used by ARP/RARP protocol to map IP to MAC and vice versa. The MAC address needs to be unique otherwise the data delivery will fail. I am wondering the NIC card manufactures are many. How do they ensure that the MAC address is unqiue? If it is not unique then the transmission will fail right? Do they speak to each other that I am using this MAC address, don't use this one? I  guess this is not the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first 6 bytes of the MAC address are a prefix that is assigned to each manufacturer by the IEEE. Manufacturer must only use prefixes that are assigned to them, and then they're responsible for ensuring that the remainder of the MAC address is unique within their products.

[IEEE Registration Authority](http://standards.ieee.org/develop/regauth/oui/index.html)